# How does Entity Framework store referenced data in the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say there is an object called `parent` which has a reference to another object called `child` as a property. After creating set of `parent` objects in a `DbContext`, I save one of them into the database. When I ask for the said object from the database, I also receive his `child` property. I cannot find where the `children` are stored. How does this mapping work?

```
public class Route
{
    public Guid Id { private set; get; }
    public Clue[] Clues { private set; get; }
}


CreateTable(
                "dbo.Routes",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

Comment: Too many possibilities without seeing either your model definition or the database definition. But the likely answer is: a foreign key defined on child referencing parent.

Comment: I use migrations and in database definition there is no foreign keys or anything. I will post model definition and migrations command

Comment: Can't tell from your question if you want a child relationship or don't want one. You've added the navigation collection Clues to Route so EF should do that implicitly (although I've never seen an example of dong it with an array). Code first can be used in different ways to define relationships: by convention, with annotations or the fluent api. I don't see annotations or fluent mappings so you are getting default conventions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link, I will check it out. But it is still a mystery for my where is the clues data saved

Comment: What do you mean "where" they are stored?

Comment: as your parent class can have many childs,
the relationship will be stored in the table of child class as foreign key.

Comment: Raj Kamal :  I also believe it should be like that but there is no foreign key. I posted code to create the table under my question.                                          Matt Rowland : Well, it's kind of obvious that the data should be in the database, but I cannot find it there. There is only one table for Routes with one column and that's all